# SDCC produces elf output with sections of NULL type

Tags: c, elf, objcopy, sdcc

I am using SDCC to produce an ELF file. I then convert this ELF file to a binary file. Sadly the output is not as expected. The output is not positioned correctly and there are strange zero length sections in the elf.

**The Questions(s)**

- How do I get SDCC not to produce NULL type sections?
- Can I remove the strange section?
- Can I use a different way to get elf output and a custom vector table?

**Example**
Take a look at the minimal example bellow:

makefile:

```
all:
    @echo makefile:
    @cat makefile
    
    @echo ivt.s:
    @cat ivt.s
    
    @echo btl.c:
    @cat btl.c
    
    sdasstm8 -l -o ivt.s.rel ivt.s
    sdcc -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mstm8 --std-sdcc11 -I src -c btl.c -o btl.c.rel
    sdcc -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mstm8 --std-sdcc11 --out-fmt-elf -Wl-bHOME=0x8080 --noivt ivt.s.rel btl.c.rel -o out.elf
    objcopy -I elf32-big -O binary out.elf out.elf.bin
    sdcc -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mstm8 --std-sdcc11 --out-fmt-ihx -Wl-bHOME=0x8080 --noivt ivt.s.rel btl.c.rel -o out.ihx
    objcopy -I ihex -O binary out.ihx out.ihx.bin
    hexdump -C out.elf.bin | head
    hexdump -C out.ihx.bin | head
```

ivt.s:

```
.module IVT
.optsdcc -mstm8

; The stm8 has a fixed ivt. it has 31 interrupts. The first is reset.
; The bootloader does not use interrupts. but the ivt is locked and protected in the UBC area.
; The application still might use interrupts so the bootloader ivt just forwards them.
; The application starts at 0x8b80 and 0x8b80 happens to the the application reset vector.
; The other vectors follow in multiples of 4.

; For simplicity the bootloader is simply compiled to an offset of 0x008080 with this ivt prepended.
; Ofcourse forwarding interrupts means every interrupt is delayed by 1 int instruction.

.area IVT (ABS)
.org 0x8000
    int 0x008080       ; reset - this enters the boot loader it is aproximately 0x8000 + (31*4)

    int 0x008B80 + 4   ; trap  - this is the trap interrupt. application reset is at 0x08b80 so the trap is +4 after that
    int 0x008B80 + 8   ; int0 - etc...
    int 0x008B80 + 12  ; int1
    int 0x008B80 + 16  ; int2
    int 0x008B80 + 20  ; int3
    int 0x008B80 + 24  ; int4
    int 0x008B80 + 28  ; int5
    int 0x008B80 + 32  ; int6
    int 0x008B80 + 36  ; int7
    int 0x008B80 + 40  ; int8
    int 0x008B80 + 44  ; int9
    int 0x008B80 + 48  ; int10
    int 0x008B80 + 52  ; int11
    int 0x008B80 + 56  ; int12
    int 0x008B80 + 60  ; int13
    int 0x008B80 + 64  ; int14
    int 0x008B80 + 68  ; int15
    int 0x008B80 + 72  ; int16
    int 0x008B80 + 76  ; int17
    int 0x008B80 + 80  ; int18
    int 0x008B80 + 84  ; int19
    int 0x008B80 + 88  ; int20
    int 0x008B80 + 92  ; int21
    int 0x008B80 + 96  ; int22
    int 0x008B80 + 100 ; int23
    int 0x008B80 + 104 ; int24
    int 0x008B80 + 108 ; int25
    int 0x008B80 + 112 ; int26
    int 0x008B80 + 116 ; int27
    int 0x008B80 + 120 ; int28
```

btl.c:

```
void main(void){
    //hal_disable_interrupts();
    
    // bla bla life is pain
}
```

You can see from the output bellow that the out.elf.bin output contains allot of zeros padded to the beginning. Strangely there are 0x7fff of them. The correct output is the out.ihx.bin output. There are no leading zeros and the instructions are aligned correctly.

```
sdasstm8 -l -o ivt.s.rel ivt.s
sdcc -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mstm8 --std-sdcc11 -I src -c btl.c -o btl.c.rel
sdcc -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mstm8 --std-sdcc11 --out-fmt-elf -Wl-bHOME=0x8080 --noivt ivt.s.rel btl.c.rel -o out.elf
at 1: warning 117: unknown compiler option '--noivt' ignored
objcopy -I elf32-big -O binary out.elf out.elf.bin
sdcc -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mstm8 --std-sdcc11 --out-fmt-ihx -Wl-bHOME=0x8080 --noivt ivt.s.rel btl.c.rel -o out.ihx
at 1: warning 117: unknown compiler option '--noivt' ignored
objcopy -I ihex -O binary out.ihx out.ihx.bin
hexdump -C out.elf.bin | head
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00007ff0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 82  |................|
00008000  00 80 80 82 00 8b 84 82  00 8b 88 82 00 8b 8c 82  |................|
00008010  00 8b 90 82 00 8b 94 82  00 8b 98 82 00 8b 9c 82  |................|
00008020  00 8b a0 82 00 8b a4 82  00 8b a8 82 00 8b ac 82  |................|
00008030  00 8b b0 82 00 8b b4 82  00 8b b8 82 00 8b bc 82  |................|
00008040  00 8b c0 82 00 8b c4 82  00 8b c8 82 00 8b cc 82  |................|
00008050  00 8b d0 82 00 8b d4 82  00 8b d8 82 00 8b dc 82  |................|
00008060  00 8b e0 82 00 8b e4 82  00 8b e8 82 00 8b ec 82  |................|
hexdump -C out.ihx.bin | head
00000000  82 00 80 80 82 00 8b 84  82 00 8b 88 82 00 8b 8c  |................|
00000010  82 00 8b 90 82 00 8b 94  82 00 8b 98 82 00 8b 9c  |................|
00000020  82 00 8b a0 82 00 8b a4  82 00 8b a8 82 00 8b ac  |................|
00000030  82 00 8b b0 82 00 8b b4  82 00 8b b8 82 00 8b bc  |................|
00000040  82 00 8b c0 82 00 8b c4  82 00 8b c8 82 00 8b cc  |................|
00000050  82 00 8b d0 82 00 8b d4  82 00 8b d8 82 00 8b dc  |................|
00000060  82 00 8b e0 82 00 8b e4  82 00 8b e8 82 00 8b ec  |................|
00000070  82 00 8b f0 82 00 8b f4  82 00 8b f8 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  82 00 80 87 cc 80 a4 ae  00 00 27 07 72 4f 00 00  |..........'.rO..|
00000090  5a 26 f9 ae 00 00 27 09  d6 80 a3 d7 00 00 5a 26  |Z&....'.......Z&|
```

The elf also contains strange sections:

```
 readelf -S out.elf
There are 10 section headers, starting at offset 0x2c5:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] IVT0              PROGBITS        00008000 000034 00007c 00   A  0   0  0
  [ 2] SSEG              PROGBITS        00000001 0000b0 000001 00   A  0   0  0
  [ 3] HOME              PROGBITS        00008080 0000b1 000007 00   A  0   0  0
  [ 4] GSINIT            PROGBITS        00008087 0000b8 00001a 00   A  0   0  0
  [ 5] GSFINAL           PROGBITS        000080a1 0000d2 000003 00   A  0   0  0
  [ 6] CODE              PROGBITS        000080a4 0000d5 000001 00   A  0   0  0
  [ 7] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0000d6 0000a0 10      8   1  0
  [ 8] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 000176 000051 00      0   0  0
  [ 9] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0001c7 00003e 00      0   0  0
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)
```

Comment: `.bin` files are flat. Byte for byte. So, when you do `.org 0x8000` you _will_ get 0x8000 zeros at the front as your hex dump shows. It isn't 0x7fff--you're misinterpreting that. More concerning is that you get spurious things in the ivt like 82 or 8b. Based on the warning that `--noivt` is ignored, I'm guessing the data is _not_ yours but the compiler is injecting its own auto-generated data instead

Comment: My bad. It's just 0x82 injected into the MSB on each 32 bit word. You wanted `0x00IJKLMN` -> `MN KL IJ 00` (little endian) but you get `MN KL IJ 82` instead.

Comment: Just a guess... Since we're talking about an IVT, could 0x82 be an 8 bit opcode for `jmp` (e.g.)?

Comment: @CraigEstey Your comment on the offset is correct, however, the observed offset is 0x7FFF. Strange, I have no idea why. -- Another discrepancy: Since Intelhex includes addresses, I would expect from the second linker call producing the hex file that it has this offset, too. And in consequence the resulting binary also.

Comment: Did you try SDCC's mailing list for users to get help? What did they say?

Answer (score 0):

> **SDCC produces elf output with sections of NULL type**
> there are strange zero length sections in the elf.

I only see one zero-length section, that is *standard* and required by the ELF specification: the first section is *required* to have `SHT_NULL` type and the other values in that section don't matter.

This doesn't answer your other questions, but your subject / initial premise is simply wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I didn't know about the standard entry. Is there a spec that I can read? The other questions, like the byte alignment and leading zeros between elf and hex output are still valid.

Comment: @Maximilian https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1386/chapter6-94076/index.html